# vor allem vs. vor Allem

Tags: spelling

How can I write A in "allem"? Is it a small or capital letter? I am using almost always with capital letter because it defines concrete things but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: To write it with uppercase "A", you would need a context where "das Alles" would be a noun. Perhaps in philosophy, this could work .... not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Vor allem is always written with a small 'a' as it is a fixed phrase meaning 'hauptsächlich, besonders, extra'.
Duden lists is as notoriously difficult to write.

Comment: I think the grammatical reason is that "allem" is considered an indefinite pronoun here, and pronouns are not capitalized in German.